# How do I stop faces extruding individually?

Tags: modeling

I'm making a model and all my faces are extruding independently, which is very useful and all, but what did I do to enable this and how do I deactivate it?

Comment: Would you mind sharing some screenshots to help give us more information about your problem? It's hard to know exactly what you're experiencing with only the description you gave there.

Comment: Can you please create a screenshot? In Blender in the top menu go to *Window > Save Screenshot*, save the file and attach it to your question.

Comment: I don't hve that opon    I'm dislexic

Comment: Can I reset controls without losing my project

Comment: i have a yellow circal with a + in it that extrudes normal

Comment: my scaling also doing it{working independently }

Comment: I'm really really confused now

Answer (score 0):

You have likely right clicked on the tool and accidentally selected *Extrude Individually*. Right click on the tool and select *Extrude Region* to get the desired behavior.

[image]

Comment: I tried but nope

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I figured out how to reset my controls. I copied and pasted my entire project into a new window and then saved it over the old one resetting my controls. I don't know why but for some reason my controls on the left side of the screen was not changing the settings it changed the icon but not the settings very peculiar. Anyway long and short all fixed